# Javascript : code for 2 dropdown box ( Hours : Minutes)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me on how to code in javascript for time which consist of 2 dropdown boxes:-

Hours : Minutes

There will be 0-12 list for Hours dropdown box

and 0-59 list for Minutes dropdown box.

Thank you..

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It only takes HTML to create two `<select>` boxes. What do you want JavaScript to do?

Comment: because im doing code in .js file. No html here. How it is possible Jordan?

Comment: In short: use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) to create your `<select>` elements and [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) to set their attributes, then do the same to create your `<option>` elements in a loop with [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) to set their text, then [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) to add them as children of the `<select>`s, and `appendChild` again to add those to your document.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/AyJKM/1/

```
function buildTimePicker() {
    var result = document.createElement('span');
    var hours = document.createElement('select');
    hours.setAttribute('id', 'hour');
    for (var h=1; h<13; h++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', h);
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h + 'h'));
        hours.appendChild(option);
    }
    var minutes = document.createElement('select');
    minutes.setAttribute('id', 'minute');
    for (var m=0; m<60; m++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', m);
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m + 'm'));
        minutes.appendChild(option);
    }
    result.appendChild(hours);
    result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" : "));
    result.appendChild(minutes);

    return result;
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(buildTimePicker());
}
```

**Edit**: added the value attributes.

Comment: No value attribute. Seriously, jQuery is 31k minified.

Comment: The use of jQuery (or any framework, for that matter) was not specified in the question. Besides, it's good to know how to do this in plain JavaScript, anyway. I think this answer is more accurate and more valuable to @Mohan.